# How can I change the i3 font on NixOS

Tags: fonts, i3, nixos

I'm trying to change my i3 font on NixOS. I've installed the font *Roboto* via `nix-env -iA nixos.roboto` and event copied it to `~/.fonts` just to cover my bases. Setting

```
font pango:Roboto 11
```

in my i3 config has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the [fonts.fonts](https://search.nixos.org/options?show=fonts.fonts&query=fonts.fonts&from=0&size=30&sort=relevance&channel=unstable) setting in your `configuration.nix`.

```
fonts.fonts = with pkgs; [ roboto ];
```

Then rebuild your system.

```
sudo nixos-rebuild switch
```

Then it will work how you'd expect.